# getting all counts returned with in an array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following querys.

```
//returns total where field callback exist and not empty
db.parts.find({callback:{"$exists" : true, "$ne" : ""}}).count();

//returns total where field callback exist and empty
db.parts.find({callback:{"$exists" : true, "$in" : [""]}}).count();

//returns total where field callback doesn't exist
db.parts.find({callback:{"$exists" : false}}).count();
```

I would like to construct a query that returns all three counts in an array like the one below.

```
{ "callbacks" : sum, "emptycallbacks" : sum, "missingcallbacks": sum }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) is what you are looking for here. You obtain the results mainly from the [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator within a [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipeline:

```js
db.parts.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "callbacks": {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$ne": [{ "$ifNull": ["$callback",""]}, "" ] },
                    1,
                    0
                ]
            }
        },
        "emptycallbacks": {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$callback", "" ] },
                    1,
                    0
                ]
            }
        },
        "missingcallbacks": {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [
                    {"$ifNull": [ "$callback", false ] },
                    0,
                    1
                ]
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

Each is using different [comparison operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-comparison/) but mainly [**`$ifNull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) to test whether the field exists in the document or not. Since `$cond` is a ternary operator, the second and third arguments are evaluated from where the condition is `true` or `false` respectively.

Those values are passed to the [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) operator to add them up. And the `null` as the grouping key means to add up everything in your collection without "grouping" on a specific field value.

Given the following documents:

```js
{ "callback" : "a" }
{ "callback" : "" }
{ "other" : "a" }
{ "callback" : "" }
{ "something" : "a" }
{ "else": "a" }
```

The result is:

```js
{ "_id" : null, "callbacks" : 1, "emptycallbacks" : 2, "missingcallbacks" : 3 }
```

Which shows all conditions are counting correctly.

You will likely need to expand on that logic for your actual documents, but this is the general direction.

Comment: Thanks Neil! I had something similar going with aggregation framework but using $exist instead and kept getting and error. 'errmsg" : "exception: invalid operator '$exists'",'

Comment: `$exists` is a query operator. You can use it in $match stage which is a query, but the intent is to "filter" documents. `$ifNull` either returns the content of the field where present or the second argument. It is used here to feed the logical evaluations.